# How can I put a "lock sreen" icon on the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, lock-screen

At first I apologize if the subject was in the wrong place
The reason is that I do not speak English
And enlisted Google to translate can I register and add this topic

I have a question:

I use Ubuntu 11.04 and I want to put lock screen icon in launcher:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is easy!

**1)** Right click on the Desktop and choose "Create Launcher".

**2)** For the name you choose what you want. "Lock Screen" for example.

**3)** At command you paste this: `gnome-screensaver-command -a`

**4)** Then drag it to the Launcher.

[image]

Enjoy ;-)